# Core data returning 0 value

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Here is my code the delivery fee is supposed to be 400 or more but core data saves the delivery fee as 0 when i print it out after it is saved also when i print out the delivery fee here print("TOTALAMT(converted)") it prints 400

```
       let cartt = Cart(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)


            var lt = String(ff.latt)
            var lg = String(ff.longg)
            var urlo = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=\(lt),\(lg)&destinations=\(self.customerLat!),\(self.customerLong!)&mode=driving&language=pl-PLe"

        print(urlo)

            var url = NSURL(string: urlo)
            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
                (data, response, error) in
                let jsonObj = JSON(data: data!)
                let yy = jsonObj["rows"][0]["elements"][0]["distance"]["value"].int
                var converted:Int?
                print(yy)
                if yy <= 5000{
                    converted = (yy! / 1000) * 80

                }else{
                    converted = (yy! / 1000) * 65

                }

                if converted <= 400{
                    converted = 400
                }



                print("TOTALAMT\(converted)")

                cartt.delivery = Int(converted!)

                }.resume()

        if let imageUrl = ff.imageUrl as? String{
            cartt.imageUrl = imageUrl
        }
        //img is from the outlet

        //save
        context.insertObject(cartt)

        do{
            try context.save()
            print(cartt.longg)
            print(cartt.delivery)
            print("saved")

        }catch{
            print("could not save ")
        }
```

Comment: You are saving the object outside of the completion handler, so the save completes before the data has been retrieved and the delivery amount set

Comment: So where should i save the object

Comment: Inside the completion handler, once all of its properties are set

Comment: Am saving the object inside the `dataTaskWithURL` completion block is that not what you mean?

Comment: You aren't but you need to. The completion block is before the `resume`

Comment: Ok it is working thank you